# Looking for software that computes intersection numbers (Heegaard Diagrams)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 3-manifolds, mathematical-software, surfaces

As a part of my research I am working with intersection matrices of Heegaard diagrams. Is there some software that could help me compute such matrices for some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Moira Chas has an applet to compute intersection numbers (although I couldn't get it to work on my laptop!): http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~moira/

Answer (score 2):

Alden Walker's "[branched](https://github.com/aldenwalker/branched)" seems to have similar functionality to Moira Chas's programs mentioned by Ian Agol. It seems to work on my machine. Here is an excerpt from the branched README file:

> Moira Chas (Stony Brook) has some Java applets on her web site
>   http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~moira/
>   which compute self-intersections of a single loop on a surface with
>   one boundary component.  branched has been tested to agree with
>   this applet on a bunch of inputs.

More broadly, Nathan Dunfield curates the website [www.CompuTop.org](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~nmd/computop/) that is probably the first place to look if the question is: "Is there software (in low dimensional topology) that does $blank$?"